# Sikulix maven project

Tags: java, maven, sikuli

I want to use **Sikulix** in my maven project but it doesn't work, I tried to add the repository like it says (http://sikulix-2014.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq/030-java-dev.html#a-comment-on-projects-using-maven) and when I do "mvn install" it says *"Could not find artifact  com.sikulix:sikulixapi:jar:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT in nexus"* where nexus is our repository.

My pom contains that:

```
...
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>com.sikulix</id>
        <name>com.sikulix</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
        <artifactId>sikulixapi</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
...
```

Any idea why maven does not find the artifact in the correct repo?

Comment: Are the repositories directly under the project root xml element of the pom? Its not inside another tag like 'dependencyManagement'?

Comment: We also have 'distributionManagement' but I also tried without it and nothing happens.
And in the .m2 at settings.xml I have the nexus 'profile'

Comment: I didn't ask that. I asked if the repositories tag is directly under the project root XML element.

Comment: Oh sorry. Yes it'sdirectly under the project root

Comment: The problem is solved. In the settings.xml we had a <mirror> so maven always used the same repo.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. How did you solve it? I assume that mirror is a repository manager you have, so you solved it by adding the additional repository there?

Comment: Well in fact I just removed the mirror because we didn't use it anymore, but I think that adding the additional repository there it would work too.

Comment: To wrap this up the Stackoverflow way I suggest you post that as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved. In the settings.xml we had a  so maven always used the same repo.

I just removed the mirror because we didn't use it anymore, but I think that adding the additional repository there it would work too.